# Kannel "0: Accepted for delivery" but not sent

Tags: kannel

I've always used smslib to connect to my SMS provider.
My SMS provider has a SMSC, and I connect in transmitter mode (not transceiver).

I'm trying to connect via Kannel, with this configuration:

```
    group = core
    admin-port = 13000
    smsbox-port = 13001
    wapbox-port = 13002
    admin-password = dad
    admin-deny-ip = ""
    admin-allow-ip = "*.*.*.*"
    wapbox-port = 13002
    wdp-interface-name = "*"
    log-file = "/var/log/kannel/kannel.log"
    log-level = 0
    box-deny-ip = ""
    box-allow-ip = "*.*.*.*"

    # NOT USED
    group = wapbox
    bearerbox-host = localhost
    log-file = "/var/log/wapbox.log"
    log-level = 0
    syslog-level = none

    group = smsbox
    bearerbox-host = localhost
    sendsms-port = 13013
    global-sender = 56951000000
    log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log"
    log-level = 0
    smsbox-id = smsbox

    group = smsc
    smsc = smpp
    smsc-id = dadn_1
    host = hidden on purpose for this post
    port = 54002
    smsc-username = dadn_1
    smsc-password = pwd_1
    system-type = smpp_1
    transceiver-mode = 0
    interface-version = 34
    allowed-smsc-id = dadn_1
    my-number = hidden on purpose for this post
    source-addr-ton = 0
    source-addr-npi = 1
    dest-addr-ton = 0
    dest-addr-npi = 1
    bind-addr-ton = 0
    bind-addr-npi = 1
    source-addr-autodetect = 1

    group = sendsms-user
    username = dad
    password = dad
    concatenation = true
    max-messages = 10

    group = sms-service
    keyword = wwwservice
    get-url = "http://......./send_dummy_mail.asp"
    concatenation = true
    catch-all = yes
```

When I call the send SMS URL, ie:

```
http://.....:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=dad&password=dad&to=....&text=test&smsc=dadn_1
```

I get this:

```
0: Accepted for delivery
```

And when I go to the status page, ie:

```
http://.....:13000status.html?password=dad
```

I get this:

```
Status: running, uptime 0d 0h 0m 45s

WDP: received 0 (0 queued), sent 0 (0 queued)

SMS: received 0 (0 queued), sent 1 (0 queued), store size -1

SMS: inbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec, outbound (0.02,0.02,0.02) msg/sec

DLR: 0 queued, using internal storage

Box connections:
    smsbox:smsbox, IP 127.0.0.1 (0 queued), (on-line 0d 0h 0m 41s) 
SMSC connections:
    dadn_1    SMPP:.......:54002/54002:dadn_1:smpp_1 (online 45s, rcvd 0, sent 1, failed 0, queued 0 msgs)
```

As you can see, it says "sent 1".

In the log, just after entering the URL, I get this:

```
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[dadn_1]: Sending PDU:
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7fb55c0016a0 dump:
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 9 = 0x00000009
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 1 = 0x00000001
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr: "56951000000"
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 1 = 0x00000001
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "..."   -- CENSORED ON PURPOSE
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   esm_class: 3 = 0x00000003
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   sm_length: 6 = 0x00000006
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   short_message: "testtt"
2014-06-12 13:31:36 [28766] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[dadn_1]: Got PDU:
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7fb55c0016a0 dump:
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 9 = 0x00000009
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG:   message_id: "122892043"
2014-06-12 13:31:37 [28766] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

As you can see, a "message_id" was assigned, etc.

However, the SMS isn't arriving to my mobile device.
If I use SMSLIB with exactly the same configuration, the SMS does arrive.. so my provider is working fine.

Questions are:

1. Is there something wrong in my Kannel configuration?
2. If I'm getting `0: Accepted for delivery`, is my provider's fault? the SMS is "there" already?

Comment: I would suggest to capture detailed dumps of SMPP sessions (both SMSlib and Kannel) with tcpdump. Then you can compare and find the difference between `submit_sm` PDU in both programs. Also you can set `registered_delivery` to 1 and possibly receive relevant diagnostics in DLR.

Comment: registered_delivery needs a transceiver connection?

Comment: Yes, `registered_delivery` requires transceiver mode or transmitter/receiver. If you want to keep transmitter only - tcpdump still should help with deeper diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note.

1. You definitely need a transmitter and receiver mode to send and receive SMS.
2. If you are using "get-url" in your sms-service, then the output of that URL invocation should be text sent to STDOUT. The name says ".../send_dummy_mail.asp". I believe that this URL returns something in STDOUT apart from sending mail. If the URL is not throwing any STDOUT then you will not get any SMS sent as response.